# Send email with Outlook application with cutomized permissions (Using PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

I'm trying to create and send emails using the Outlook application with PowerShell applying Permissions for the email (Example: Encrypt-Only, Do Not Forward, etc.), is currently working on the outlook application (when creating the email manually), however, couldn't find a way to send emails using PowerShell applying this setting:

[Permission templates in Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsNGp.png)

I'm currently using the following code to create and send the emails (Working):

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem("olMailItem")
$Mail.To = "test@test.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Test Email"
$Mail.Body = "Email sent using PowerShell"
$file = "C:\ExampleFolder\test.txt"
$Mail.Attachments.Add($file)
$Mail.Send()
```

Is there a way to apply this setting using PowerShell?

Comment: I founded that if the property $Mail.Permission is set to "1" before sending the email the option olDoNotForward is triggered on the email, however, this is not the perfect scenario, since there are more permissions templates and I'm not pretty sure how to change the properties "PermissionTemplateGuid" and "PermissionService" for the MailItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the solution for this, this solution involve two properties: "$Outlook.CreateItem("olMailItem").Permission" and "$Outlook.CreateItem("olMailItem").PermissionTemplateGuid", and work as follow:

- **If $Outlook.CreateItem("olMailItem").Permission is set to "0"**: The email is sent as unrestricted message, no PermissionTemplateGuid is needed for this value.
- **If $Outlook.CreateItem("olMailItem").Permission is set to "1"**: The email is sent as olDoNotForward automatically, no PermissionTemplateGuid is needed for this value.
- **If $Outlook.CreateItem("olMailItem").Permission is set to "2"**: The email require a PermissionTemplateGuid, therefore, it's required to get the GUID of the template, since each organization have a different template according with the configuration, send an email with the encryption template to your inbox and read it using the following code:

```
$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$items = $inbox.items
$items[1].PermissionTemplateGuid
```

This is going to provide the correct permissionTemplateGuid with the desired encryption.

Therefore, to send the email the following formula works:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem("olMailItem")
$Mail.To = "test@test.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Test Email"
$Mail.Body = "Email sent using PowerShell"
$file = "C:\ExampleFolder\test.txt"
$Mail.Attachments.Add($file)
$Mail.PermissionTemplateGuid = XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
$Mail.Permission = "2"
$Mail.Send()
```

For more information visit this website: http://jon.glass/blog/reads-e-mail-with-powershell/